# How to use snake case for file names and camel case for file names in CLion?

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

When I create new class `MyClass`, CLion creates `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp`, but I want `my_class.h` and `my_class.cpp`. And when I try to rename files it renames class to `class my_class {}`. How can I have `class MyClass {}` and `my_class.h`, `my_class.cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write some Apache Velocity engine code to do that. Inside the CLion preferences you can adjust the file creation template settings (something like that, I don't have CLion open here to look it up) and write something like:

```
#set( $CamelCaseName = "" )
#set( $part = "" )
#foreach($part in $NAME.split("-"))
    #set( $CamelCaseName = "${CamelCaseName}$part.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()$part.substring(1).toLowerCase()" )
#end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go to "Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C/C++ -> New File Extensions" and change "File Naming Convention".