# Change variable naming style for C++ in CLion

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

In CLion, the default naming style for local variables is `camelCase`. The C++ codebase that I'm working in has a convention of using `snake_case` for this. Is there any way to change the naming style for categories of symbols (local variables, instance variables, etc.)?

I would expect such a setting to appear in **Settings** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **C/C++** > **Code Generation**, but no such luck.

[image: Screenshot of Settings > Editor > Code Style > C/C++]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use snake case for file names and camel case for file names in CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037467/how-to-use-snake-case-for-file-names-and-camel-case-for-file-names-in-clion)

Comment: That question relates to file names; mine is regarding the names of symbols in the actual code.

Comment: Only request in JetBrains bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Code Style > C/C++ > Naming Convention

This is a [new feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/02/clion-2019-1-eap-naming-conventions/) in CLion as of release 2019.1.